# Upload file to ZenDesk using Java Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, zendesk

I am attempting to replicate, using java and Jersey, uploading a file to ZenDesk, to be used as an attachment on a ticket. The example code from ZenDesk uses curl with a --data-binary parameter, referencing a file on disk.
I am using an SDK client that I found on git as my starting point, everything about this SDK works with the exception of file uploads.

Here is the code that I currently have doing the upload:

```
        File fileToUpload = new File(attachment.getUrl());
        
        FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart(attachment.getFilename(), fileToUpload, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE); 
        
        FormDataContentDisposition.FormDataContentDispositionBuilder builder = FormDataContentDisposition.name(filePart.getName());
        builder.fileName(fileToUpload.getName());
        builder.size(fileToUpload.length());
        filePart.setFormDataContentDisposition(builder.build());
        
        FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
        multiPart.bodyPart(filePart);
        multiPart.field("filename", attachment.getFilename());
        
        ClientResponse cr = rootResource.path("/api/v2/uploads.json")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
//              .post(AttachmentWrapper.class, attachment);
                .post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart);
```

This results in an internal server error 500 response from ZenDesk.

I have tried several different arrangements of the parameters, with no success.
The project that I'm using as a starting point is located here: [Zendesk-API-Client](https://github.com/pryadav84/Zendesk-API-Client)

The problem with the original project is that the file being uploaded doesn't have its content available on the ZenDesk server, it is just the JSON defining the file.

Thanks,

Allen

Comment: I've given up for the time being, and I'm shelling out to use command line curl.